# switch cases in Observable map Rxswift

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-programming, rx-swift

I have in a viewmodel a reactive closure to return and sort data from a network call based on type (shipping or billing).

```
Observable.combineLatest(input.headerRefresh, type).flatMapLatest({ (header, type) -> Observable<[AddressItemViewModel]> in
    var els : Observable<[AddressItemViewModel]>

     els = self.request()
        .trackActivity(self.loading)
        .trackActivity(self.headerLoading)
        .trackError(self.error)

    return els.map{
        $0.map {
            print(type)
            var item  : AddressItemViewModel!
            switch(type){
            case .shipping:
                if($0.address.isShipping){
                    item = AddressItemViewModel(with: $0.address)
                }

            case .billing:
                if($0.address.isBilling){
                    item = AddressItemViewModel(with: $0.address)
                }
            }

            return item // error
        }
    }

   }).subscribe(onNext: { (items) in
        elements.accept(items)
    }).disposed(by: rx.disposeBag)
```

When subscribed to `elements` in the view controller, the app crash at `return item`.

So my question is how to sort items without using nullable objects? Thanks.

The error :

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an
>   Optional value

Comment: Your issue is that your `switch` is based on `type` (a parameter to the closure), whereas your if statements are based on the `isShipping` and `isBilling` fields of `$0.address`. If `type` is `.billing`, and `$0.isBilling` is false, then no assignment will be done, and `item` will be `nil`.

Comment: yes, am aware of this, what is the best way to handle this ? thanks.

Comment: To answer that, I'd need more context as to what your'e trying to achieve. What's `type`, and what does it mean for it to match or not match the value of `$0.address.isX`?

Comment: Ironically, on this line `var item  : AddressItemViewModel!` if you removed the `!` from the end of it, the compiler would have told you that it was going to crash and why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem might be this line:

```
var item  : AddressItemViewModel!
```

Using implicitly unwrapped variable can lead to fatal error. Think what happens when your `type` is set to `.shipping` and `$0.address.isShipping` is set to `false` (or `type` is `billing` and `$0.address.isBilling` is `false`)? The `item` variable will be set to `nil`, but the type of `item` require to be a non-nil. I think the best option will be to use `compactMap` instead of `map` to pass only non-nil values:

```
 $0.compactMap {
      switch(type){
           case .shipping where $0.address.isShipping:
                fallthrough
           case .billing where $0.address.isBilling:
               return AddressItemViewModel(with: $0.address)
           default:
               return nil
      }
    }
```

Comment: You could even use `fallthrough` to eliminate the repetition of `return AddressItemViewModel(with: $0.address)`

Comment: Thank you Alexander and bazyl.

Comment: @MohamedALOUANE if this answers your question, please  accept it